# Get attribute value in Capybara

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, capybara

I have an HTML partial that looks like this:

```
<input id="order_date" name="order_date" class="date-applied"
 onchange="restoreDate=false;" type="text" value="01/05/2016" 
 size="12" maxlength="10"/>
```

I need to retrieve the value of attribute `value` using Capybara.  I have tried using this code, without success:

```
find(:xpath,"//table[2']/tbody/tr[7]/td[@name='order_date]")['value']
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906994/capybara-is-it-possible-to-get-an-attribute-value-from-a-css-string

Comment: Have tried the above solution as well. it retrieves nil when tried to get with the attribute [:'value'] or [:value]. not sure what i was missing.

Comment: @Jon I don't believe that this is a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906994/capybara-is-it-possible-to-get-an-attribute-value-from-a-css-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906994/capybara-is-it-possible-to-get-an-attribute-value-from-a-css-string), as asks how to query.  With this question, however, it appears that the OP knows how to do this, but simply can't get it to work.  They are certainly related, but I don't believe that they're the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might check that your xpath returns a value.  The xpath that you used as an example has multiple syntax errors.  Try this, instead:

```
find(:xpath, "//table[2]/tbody/tr[7]/td/input[@name="order_date"]")['value']
```

I created a structurally correct test document based on what it appears you're searching for.  The xpath above found the input element in this document:

```
<document>
    <table></table>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="order_date" name="order_date" class="date-applied"
                     onchange="restoreDate=false;" type="text" value="01/05/2016" 
                     size="12" maxlength="10"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for the great explanation. It worked. i missed the input[] tag in the code as you mentioned.. the quote marks , i mistyped it.