# How to get the img URL of an element in Ruby Selenium WebDriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

super noob here so i apologize in advance for any dumb question...

I am trying to create a script that finds and image by :id, saves it's image URL (named also img src), and then clicks on the image.

so far i've done:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'selenium-webdriver'

    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for:firefox
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)

    driver.get 'http://example.com'

    image = wait.until {
        element = driver.find_element(:id,'id_image')
        element if element.displayed?
    }
    #this is the part where i would like to save the IMAGE URL 
    image click.click
```

I just took the relevant part of the code, i can assure you that so far it all works perfectly but i just can't save the IMAGE URL.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want the href attribute of the element. In selenium you get attributes using `element.attribute('attribute-name')`

In your case you would do something like:

```
href = image.attribute('href')
```

Comment: I've been trying for a while but still can't manage to get that value. I've tried: 
`puts image['href']` 
and 
`puts image.attribute('href')` 

but still can't get anything... what am i missing?

Comment: You're probably selecting the wrong element then. Try selecting the <a> element of the image instead.

Comment: it worked! had to use the xpath to locate the element and in the end i was looking for the attribute ('src')

Comment: Next time I suggest you post your html you're trying to select :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) since it has several useful selectors.

At this way, you could get the URL attribute with something like this:

```
href = driver.find_element(:id, 'id_image')[href]
```

Related question:
[Capybara: is it possible to get an attribute value from a css string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906994/capybara-is-it-possible-to-get-an-attribute-value-from-a-css-string)